# "of which" (there?) still can be grasped the traces?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, word-order, grammaticality-in-context

I have to translate a text from Italian into English and I am going crazy with this sentence... could you help me in fixing it? This is my try:

This represents an effective portrayal of the ancient wealth and the building texture, far from those of today but of which there still can be grasped the traces.

Comment: Can you describe what "building texture" is? Also "traces"? As written it doesn't make sense. You might also add the original phrase. Also, be sure to capitalize language names.

Comment: @user3169 , 
Building texture is like the urban texture, but with more focus on the buildings: in italian is called "tessuto edilizio". 
for "traces" I mean the "tracks" of this ancient ""urban texture"", which have been searched and found by the author of this research.

Comment: Does "*building texture*" = architecture?

Comment: @Peter it is a technical term, it relates to architecture but it indicates the texture of the buildings "web" in a town, You might also substitute that word with "urban texture" if it is easier for you,..even if actually its meaning is slightly different. Anyway my concern was about the construction of the sentence, whether it sounds grammatically correct or not

Comment: This canvas depicts a good example of [Roman or Renaissance] wealth and building textures, far removed from those of today but ***traces of which can still be glimpsed***. It is not grasped, it's glimpsed. And I assume this is a tourist site text. ancient is not right. What is your actual word there??

Answer (score 0):

Part by part:

> This represents an effective portrayal

To say something is a "*portrayal*" would mean something "*new*" has been built to represent something "*old*", or is it something already in existence?

> of the ancient wealth and building texture,

you are linking "*ancient wealth*" to "*building texture*", that "*building texture*" is part of the "*wealth*"

> far *removed* from those of today

meaning "*modern building texture*" is very different than "*ancient building texture*"

> but of which there still can be grasped the traces.

Your original is too wordy, by "*grasped*" I think you mean "*observable*", possibly consider

> but of which the original influences can still be seen.
>   but traces of the original can still be seen.

"*original*" referring to "*ancient building texture*"

Comment: Here the full paragraph:
It is indeed the church of *****, majestically emerging in the axonometric representation of **nameofthevillage*** depicted in the canvas, which makes itself the cornerstone and the joint of an urban context equipped with two access gates, fortified walls, noble palaces and towers on top.
This canvas represents an effective portrayal of the ancient wealth and building texture, which were far removed from those of today, but whose traces are still observable.

Comment: @ValentEEna Your are definitely in need of editing help. This kind of text should only be done by a native English speaker. (I am a translator, by the way). Your entire paragraph there is all screwy. :)